# How do I open a text file when I don't know where the program folder is?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to (in my menu-strip) open the update log from my program. I have an .msi for it, but the problem is that I don't know where the user will install the program. For example, in my code I could put the path of `C:\Program Files\Colour Picker\updatelog.txt`. But what if the user installed the program elsewhere? They would try to open the update log text file and be presented with an error.

Possibly there is a way to open the text file from the install location. So in pseudocode,

```
OPEN updatelog.txt(InstallLocation).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get where the application is stored is by using `My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath`.

[Here's the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo.directorypath?view=netframework-4.8)

Using this in combination with a `TextReader` or `StreamReader` should work well enough for you.

Without knowing your specific implementation, I can't offer a specific answer. If you update your question, I'll refine my answer. For now, I believe this may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Log files are best kept in a location different from the application installation folder. You won't want to get tripped up by administrative access requirements.

For example, as a best practice you could use something like this:

```
Dim sLogFile As String = "UpdateLog.txt"
Dim sAppData As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
Dim sAppName As String = "Colour Picker"
Dim sLogPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(sAppData, sAppName, sLogFile)
```

If you want to make the log file user-accessible, you can provide a means to open it in your UI and point to that location.